# PHP scope in Slim Framework 3

Tags: php, slim

I think this is probably an easy question.  Can someone help me determine how to best access the `$route` variable inside each of my router functions?  I'm trying to add a lot of Slim 3 router functions from an array.  The following code is from **/src/routes.php**:

```
<?php
// Standard CRUD Routes (based on templates)

$app->group('/api/v1', function () use ($app) {

  $routes = [
    'calendar' => [
      'table' => 'calendar',
      'prefix' => 'cal',
      'sort' => 'cal_name_orig',
      'fields' => ['cal_name_orig','cal_name_tran','cal_public','cal_color'],
      'permRead' => 1,
      'permWrite' => 1
    ],
    'classroom' => [
      'table' => 'classroom',
      'prefix' => 'room',
      'sort' => 'room_name',
      'fields' => ['room_owner_p_id','room_name','room_common','room_capacity_normal','room_capacity_max','room_current_desks'],
      'permRead' => 1,
      'permWrite' => 1
    ]
  ];

  // register all standard routes using above data
  foreach ($routes as $key => $route) {
    echo "<br><br>ROUTE: $key<br>";
    print_r($route);

    // Add Route: retrieve all records
    $app->get('/' . $key . 's', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      return $this->common->getAll($route['table'], $route['prefix'], $route['sort'], $route['permRead']);
    });

    // Add Route: retrieve specific record
    $app->get('/' . $key . '/[{id}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      return $this->common->getById($route['table'], $route['prefix'], $args['id'], $route['permRead']);
    });

    // Add Route: create new record
    $app->put('/' . $key . '/new', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      return $this->common->putNew($route['table'], $route['prefix'], $route['fields'], $route['permWrite']);
    });

    // Add Route: update specific record
    $app->post('/' . $key . '/[{id}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      return $this->common->postById($route['table'], $route['prefix'], $args['id'], $route['fields'], $route['permWrite']);
    });

    // Add Route: delete specific record
    $app->delete('/' . $key . '/[{id}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      return $this->common->deleteById($route['table'], $route['prefix'], $args['id'], $route['permWrite']);
    });
  }

});
```

As you might suspect, the error I'm getting is `Notice: Undefined variable: route in C:\Wamp\www\ravine\server\src\routes.php on line 46`.

The foreach loop is working and displaying each of the routes to the screen (for debugging purposes).  Note that all of the `$this->common->` functions are custom functions I've written and I am confident they're working fine (as long as I can pass them the correct parameters).

How can/should I access `$route` from the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $app->put('/' . $key . '/new', function ($request, $response, $args) use ($route) {
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I've been using PHP for many years... but never understood the "use" keyword.  So that basically brings the scope into the function?

Comment: Yes, to be simple: "use" makes it possible, to use variables from outside :)